# How to check if ZLIB compression is enabled in hive tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, compression, zlib, orc

I see compression attribute set as no in desc.

How I created table:

*create table temp (.....) 
stored as orc 
tblproperties("orc.compress"="ZLIB")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use orcfiledump utility:

```
hive --orcfiledump hdfs://table_location
```

It will print orc file metadata, statistics, compression information.

Compression information looks like this:

```
Rows: 95
Compression: SNAPPY
Compression size: 262144
```

See manual here: [ORC File Dump Utility](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility)

Also hive command `describe formatted table_name` prints Table Parameters and there is `orc.compress` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is `describe formatted` statement.

When your fire this command with the following syntax

```
describe formatted <your table name>
```

**you will see some output on your screen and a portion of it will look like below.**

```
# Detailed Table Information             
Database:               default                  
Owner:                  edureka_268377           
CreateTime:             Thu Feb 22 04:56:05 UTC 2018     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Protect Mode:           None                     
Retention:              0                        
Location:               hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/tests3   
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE            
Table Parameters:                
        orc.compress            ZLIB                
        transient_lastDdlTime   1519275365          

# Storage Information            
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde        
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat  
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat         
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:             
        serialization.format    1
```

Pay attention to the **Table Parameters** section. It has a property called `orc.compress`. It says **ZLIB**. So **ZLIB** is your compression codec. If it is SNAPPY or something else, it will be mentioned there. **If it is blank, the compression codec is ZLIB, the default one!**

Hope that helps!

Comment: It has a row with `Compressed: No`. What does that indicate?